# Set minimum price in input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, min, minimum

I am trying to set a minimum price of 300 for all of my vendors using jQuery. For some reason, it doesn't seem to work out for me.

I've tried using .attr() in order to set minimum price for all vendor products but no luck.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         if ($('body.role-wc_product_vendors_admin_vendor').length > 0)
    {
    $("input#_regular_price").attr({
       "min" : 300          // Set minimum price
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$("input#_regular_price").attr({
   "min" : 300          // Set minimum price
});
```

to

```
$("input#_regular_price").attr("min", 300);
```

Comment: Thank you! It change have been applied on site, but for some reason, the site will still allow input numbers below 300. I have cleared cache and made sure the script is loaded correctly.

Comment: You can get more info from here - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp